# c# DataGridView doesn't display data

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView which I put on a form using the designer. I'm trying to display some data by programmatically creating rows. The code is below. This DataGridView displays nothing at all, it might as well be an empty label or panel. I've looked at other questions regarding empty DataGridViews and tried all the suggestions. One common suggestion is "Just set AutoGenerateColumns to true, it will solve the problem." That did not work. I've tried implementing a DataTable and binding to the DataSource on the DataGridView. That did not work either.

Using the debugger in VisualStudio, I tried looking at the row properties/column properties/cell properties (within each row). The row and cell properties both have a "Displayed" property, which is set to false. This seems to be a read-only property, I can't set it to true (I get an error when I try). Apparently this property can be set to true or false to show or hide rows or cells, but I can't set it to anything.

After trying a lot of things, I ended up with the minimal test code below, which should work, but still doesn't.

What am I doing wrong?

```
int M = 2, N = 2;

dgvSpreadSheet.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
dgvSpreadSheet.ColumnCount = N;
dgvSpreadSheet.Rows.Clear();
for (int ix = 0; ix < N; ix++) 
    dgvSpreadSheet.Columns[ix].Name = "Column " + (ix + 1).ToString();

for (int ix = 0; ix < M; ix++)
{
    string[] row = new string[N];
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
        row[j] = "Test";
    }

    dgvSpreadSheet.Rows.Add(row);
    dgvSpreadSheet.Rows[ix].HeaderCell.Value = "Header" + (ix + 1).ToString();
}

dgvSpreadSheet.RowHeadersWidth = 200;
dgvSpreadSheet.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
dgvSpreadSheet.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
dgvSpreadSheet.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
```

Comment: `AutoGenerateColumns` requires a datasource but it looks like (kind of) you want to tediously poke data into the control bit by bit.  Create a datatable or collection of whatever you are working with and use that.  It would also probably be more fruitful to visit MSDN and read about the tool you are trying to use rather than trial and error

Comment: Like I indicated in my question above, I did try the datatable. I also tried a list of objects of a particular class. I can post those codes if needed.

Comment: Delete the DGV from form and then start from fresh.  You probably have set some properties incorrectly.  Then use the DataTable method as just use datagridview1.DataSource = dt;

Comment: I actually built two separate forms to test this out, it didn't work on either one of them. It's possible that some properties are incorrect, I'll give it a try again. I did visit MSDN. The code above comes from examples and tutorials online. It's probably something very silly that I'm getting wrong. I had it working on another form a year or so ago. I even tried copying the code from that application, it still didn't work (in the new application). That old application still works. I've been back and forth, comparing properties on the gridview between both applications. They're the same. :(.

Comment: As @jdweng points out, you are either doing something AFTER the above code is run… or you are doing something in the “designer” (setting some property) to cause the `DataGridView` to not display the two rows as the above code does. I created a new win forms project, added an empty `DataGridGridView` to the form, added the code above to the `Form_Load` event and two rows with two columns displayed properly. Something else is going on that you are not showing in the code above.

Comment: @jdweng I deleted the DGV from my form and started fresh, this did not solve the problem. However, it seems you are still correct (see my response to JohnG below).

Comment: @JohnG I created a new project like you said and added my code to the Form_Load event. This worked, and I see the two rows and columns now. So you and jdweng are both correct, there is something else going on. I hope to figure this out soon, if I do, I'll come back and post what was wrong.

Comment: I never figured out what was wrong with my first two forms which didn't work. I just continued using the new project that I created (as suggested by @JohnG). Thanks for the replies, all.